# Use python to find html or js tags. (regex?)

Tags: python, html, regex

I am also open to other solutions other than using regex. 
would checking angle brackets be enough? 
any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit: what I need is NOT to parse html tags but just to check it has those tags or not

Comment: I am glad that you are open to other solutions, because you are dangerously close to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/763505 .

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: what I need is not to parse html tags but just to check it has those tags or not.

Comment: @Bobo you should be very careful with putting html and regex into single sentence - it triggers a lot of "sighs" here on SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) parser and check if there are any tags by iterating the `BeautifulSoup` object and checking if there is at least one `Tag` element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

l = ['test', 'test <br>', '<br>']
for item in l:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item, 'html.parser')
    print item, any(isinstance(element, Tag) for element in soup)
```

prints:

```
test False
test <br> True
<br> True
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend **lxml.html** to do anything regarding parsing (xml, html, xhtml ...)
to get the whole idea just have a quick look at these [graphs](http://svn.colorstudy.com/home/ianb/python-html-perf/results.html) and you will know what i am talking about ;)

for a more detailed comparision have a look [here](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2008/03/python-html-parser-performance.html).